# SQL query optimization in where clause while passing arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, left-join

I have this SQL query:

```
    SELECT 
        @ComplianceCountAtAssociateDeptLevel = COUNT(FILUP.[FileUploadId])
        ,@TotalCountAtAssociateDeptLevel     = COUNT(AD.[Associate_ID])
    FROM 
        [CentralRepository].[dbo].[vw_CentralRepository_Associate_Details] AD WITH(NOLOCK)
        LEFT  JOIN 
                 (select [FileUploadId],[AssociateID] from [CentralRepository].[dbo].   [vw_CentralRepository_FileUploadDetails]
                 where Fk_AppTemplateId =2  OR Fk_AppTemplateId=1 ) FILUP 
    ON AD.[Associate_ID] = FILUP.[AssociateID] 
    WHERE 
        AD.[Dept_ID] = 'SC00002'
```

it is fetching results with in 5 sec.

But the same code is taking a long time when declaring the `Dept_ID` argument as:

```
declare @Dept varchar(30) = 'SC00002',
```

and passing it to the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
 WHERE
    AD.[Dept_ID] = @Dept
```

Please help me.

Comment: Yes - obviously. In the first case, the query optimizer can optimize **for that ONE single value** - so it can find a good, fast execution plan. In the second case, the optimizer must optimize for **any potential possible value** - so it might pick a less optimal plan *for that one value* that you have.

Comment: what's the datatype of the column `AD.[Dept_ID]`?

Comment: @marc_s, shouldn't parameter sniffing make both cases equal except maybe the parameter type?

Comment: @Paolo - its varchar

Comment: Guys, how to solve this scenario?

Comment: @PraveenVR varchar without a number [is varchar(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). is that the datatype of your column?

Comment: The way to solve it that you compare the execution plans. My guess is that it can't use an index seek in the second case due to an implicit conversion somewhere.

Comment: @Paolo - varchar(30)

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Is this a stored procedure or just a blob of SQL you are working with?